# Custom styling for Ant Design Steps connector?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, antd

I'm looking for a way to customize the color/width of the connector line in Ant Designs Steps component:
[image: What I want to update]

I've tried looking through the inspector but the connector doesn't appear as it's own element which means I can't style it through className.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `.ant-steps-item-title` class to achieve this. For example:

```
.ant-steps-item-title:after {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-p8qdd?file=/index.css:41-108)

Comment: Works perfectly! Such a weird fix though lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may decide to use `sx` attribute on `Stepper`:

```js
<Stepper
  sx={{
    ...
    '& .MuiStepConnector-line.MuiStepConnector-lineHorizontal': {
      borderColor: 'red',
    },
  }}
/>
```

That way you avoid to user `!important` that isn't recommended.
Same way you may use another attributes like `width` and `color`.